# Nextjs13 : All pages inside App directory are server-side rendered even though some of them are static

Tags: next.js, next.js13

**All pages inside my app directory are server side**

i copied the same file (auth/signup == pages/signupPage)  to the pages directory and it shows that's its static but in the app dir its ssr
any idea ?
and for some reason the first load js sizes are too big even though most of the files do not contain much

```
Route (app)                                      Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /[locale]                                    10.2 kB         275 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/forgot-password               2.7 kB          245 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/login                         8.33 kB         275 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/register                      27 kB           270 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/register-as-dealer            6.5 kB          282 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/reset-password                3.12 kB         246 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/signup                        3.71 kB         171 kB
├ λ /[locale]/auth/verify-email                  979 B           215 kB
├ λ /[locale]/checkout/[id]                      10.6 kB         265 kB
├ λ /[locale]/loading                            170 B           248 kB
├ λ /[locale]/product/[id]                       21.6 kB         302 kB
├ λ /[locale]/products                           3.67 kB         243 kB
├ λ /[locale]/stores/[id]                        7.6 kB          253 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/messages           4.65 kB         218 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/overview           4.15 kB         245 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/profile            7.41 kB         250 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/security-settings  8.67 kB         267 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/sell               3.95 kB         217 kB
├ λ /[locale]/users/dashboard/tracking-orders    4.46 kB         218 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/payment            3.5 kB          262 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/policies           4.63 kB         218 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/profile            4.51 kB         280 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/security           5.58 kB         248 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/settings           10 kB           253 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/vat                6.13 kB         220 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/account/verification       4.61 kB         229 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/buying                     6.61 kB         256 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/chat                       6.09 kB         220 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/complete-registration      2.8 kB          261 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/dashboard                  7.21 kB         232 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/listings                   4.37 kB         258 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/listings/create            4.06 kB         242 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/listings/create-listing    619 B           280 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/listings/edit/[id]         595 B           280 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/orders                     5.55 kB         254 kB
├ λ /[locale]/vendors/reviews                    5.81 kB         219 kB
└ λ /[locale]/vendors/store                      5.9 kB          257 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                    78.5 kB
  ├ chunks/2961-1374ad2754bde8b2.js              25.3 kB
  ├ chunks/bce60fc1-28f7ce62d8891bb3.js          50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-49f014b4bc536184.js          223 B
  └ chunks/webpack-aaa6b78acbbd5050.js           2.47 kB

Route (pages)                                    Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /404                                         185 B          76.7 kB
├ λ /api/auth/[...nextauth]                      0 B            76.5 kB
├ ○ /keep                                        239 B          76.7 kB
└ ○ /signupPage (653 ms)                         28.3 kB         105 kB
    └ css/74f526e20b05ceab.css                   2.11 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                    76.5 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-4ad0cc0801c690bb.js         45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-e235c17734340276.js              28.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-8af45f6c5c3cbc8e.js        201 B
  └ chunks/webpack-aaa6b78acbbd5050.js           2.47 kB

ƒ Middleware                                     52.7 kB
```

Comment: Are you using the `cookies()` or `headers()` function anywhere in those pages? This will make the page dynamic. If not, you can enforce static pages via [route segment configurations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config).

Comment: i'm not using cookies() nor headers() but enforcing it via route segments seems to work ! thank you